# Install unsigned drivers in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, remote, htpc, ir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use an unsigned driver in Windows 7 x64](https://superuser.com/questions/124112/use-an-unsigned-driver-in-windows-7-x64)

This question was never answered. I ask again because I need a way install unsigned drivers on Windows 7 so I can use my IR remote. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Duplicated a few times...here are a couple: http://superuser.com/questions/124112/use-an-unsigned-driver-in-windows-7-x64, http://superuser.com/questions/333134/how-to-install-unsigned-drivers-on-windows-7

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Disable Driver Signing.

Follow these steps to disable driver signing using the Group Policy Editor.

- Hit the Win+R keys together to open the run dialog. Type **gpedit.msc** to open the local groups policy editor.
- Expand ‘User Configuration’ -> ‘Administrative Templates’ -> ‘System’. Click ‘Driver Installation’.
- In the right panel, double click on ‘Code Signing for Device Drivers’.
- Choose ‘Enabled’ in the window that appears. In the underlying options, choose ‘Ignore’. This disables drivers signing in Windows 7, and now you can install unsigned drivers in Windows 7.
- Click Apply. Restart your computer to install unsigned drivers.

Comment: Thanks, I hope you get the points I gave you even if the superuser admins blacklist every duplicate without checking if there's an accepted answer meanning that it solved the problem is in one duplicate at least ...

Comment: Does not work in a domain with group policies.

Comment: Does not work outside of a domain either, apparently.